# jQuery detect events of dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table

```
<table id="table1">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><input type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

A new row is added when enter is pressed on the input box

```
$('[type=text]').on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        var newRow = '<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>';
        $('#table1 tbody tr').last().after(newRow);
    }
});
```

It works fine for the 1st row. However, any event on the dynamically added newRow is not detected.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach event to parent element which exists on the page. Read more about [event delegation](http://javascript.info/tutorial/event-delegation).

```
$('#table1').on('keyup', '[type=text]', function(e){

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the handler on an element further up the DOM, and then filter it. Checkout the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for all info. But in your case, this should work:

```
$('#table1').on('keyup', '[type="text"]', function(e) {
    // your code
});
```

Whenever attaching the event to a parent element, please make sure to choose the lowest element possible. Attaching to `document` is usually a bad idea, as you'll get a performance penalty (because the handler will be fired *anytime* a key is hit, not somewhere in the DOM element you selected...).

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a click handler on an element that doesn't exist. You should use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Try this:

```
$("#table1").on('keyup','[type=text]', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        var newRow = '<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>';
        $('#table1 tbody tr').last().after(newRow);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/txpww0bz/)

Answer (score 0):

You simply change `on()` with `live()`, in `jQuery<=1.7`, like this:

```
$(selector).live( eventName, function(){} );
```

Which is:

```
$('[type=text]').live('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        var newRow = '<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>';
        $('#table1 tbody tr').last().after(newRow);
    }
});
```

Or, in `jQuery>1.7`, better use:

```
$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});
```

So:

```
 $('#table1').on('keyup', '[type=text]', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            var newRow = '<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>';
        $('#table1 tbody tr').last().after(newRow);
    }
 });
```

Hope it's useful!

Answer (score -1):

Another method different from the ones presented here so far is to attach the error handler to the newly created element in the keypress handler...

Comment: While I agree and think it's possibly the better solution, you should probably provide code and a better explanation (I'm not the downvoter, although I understand why), otherwise just leave a comment